# How prove this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

**Question:**

let $f(x)\gt0(x\geqslant0)$ is increasing function, let three sequence
$\{a_{n}\},\{b_{n}\},\{c_{n}\}$, such $a_{n}\geqslant 0,b_{n}\geqslant 0,c_{n}\geqslant 0$ and
$$a_{n+1}\leqslant a_{n}-b_{n}f(a_{n})+c_{n}a_{n},\sum_{b=1}^{\infty}b_{n}=\infty,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}\lt\infty$$

show that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=0$$

since 
$$a_{n+1}-a_{n}\leqslant -b_{n}f(a_{n})+c_{n}a_{n}$$
so
$$a_{n}-a_{1}\leqslant -(b_{1}f(a_{1})+b_{2}f(a_{2})+\cdots+b_{n-1}f(a_{n-1}))+c_{1}a_{1}+c_{2}a_{2}+\cdots+c_{n-1}a_{n-1}$$

Then I am stuck , it is said this is hard analysis problem.and I want know this problem how prove it,Thank you

Comment: Let $f(x) = x$, $a_n = 1$, $b_n = 1$, $c_n = 0$. Then the conditions on the sequences are satisfied but $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 1$.

Comment: Sorry,I have edit.Sorry

Comment: Dude, you should replace all of your 'then i cant' then 'i am stuck'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $x_n=a_n/d_n$, $1\le d_n=(1+c_1)...(1+c_{n-1})\le d_*<\infty$. Then

$$x_{n+1}\le x_n-b_n\frac{f(d_nx_n)}{d_{n+1}}\le x_n-b_n\frac{f(x_n)}{d_*}.$$

This reduced form should still be sufficient to exclude convergence towards any positive limit.

---

For the first step notice that rearranging the given inequality reads as

$$a_{n+1}\le (1+c_n)a_n-b_nf(a_n)$$

So dividing by $d_{n+1}$ gives $\frac{(1+c_n)a_n}{d_{n+1}}=\frac{a_n}{d_n}=x_n$. Note that $d_n$ is increasing and bounded by
$$d_n\le e^{c_1+\dots+c_{n-1}}\le\exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_n\right)<\infty,$$

so there exists a limit $d_*=\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n=\sup_{n\to\infty}d_n$.

Comment: Hello,the first step I can't understand,can you detaile your post? Thank you,and then follow How can?

Comment: Oh,But if $x_{n+1}\le x_{n}-b_{n}\dfrac{f(x_{n})}{d_{*}}$,How prove$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=0?$$Thank you

Comment: Then $x_*=\inf x_n>0$ and $f(x_n)\ge f(x_*)>0$, can you see why this would be impossible?

Comment: I don't know,can you post why?I guess $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}=\infty$contradiction? $$x_{n}-x_{n+1}\ge f(x_{n})/d\cdot b_{n}\Longrightarrow x_{1}-x_{n}=(x_{1}-x_{2})+(x_{2}-x_{3})+\cdots+(x_{n-1}-x_{n})\ge \cdots?$$

Comment: Yes, exactly. Now use that x is decreasing and f has a positive lower bound on the sequence.